# strcmp() in C not giving accurate value when run on linux server

Tags: c, string, cgi

I am trying to compare two strings in my c program with a .csv files input. Everything works fine when I run it on my localhost as a cgi-program. But upon uploading on to linux server it doesn't compare properly. The output file shows despite being the same value it's compared output is different. And I think the linux server is running C99 compiler for C.
I have only pasted the code where it creates the problem. If you want to take a look at the full code follow the link please https://github.com/iaminhri/CGI-Programming/blob/main/checkpass2.c Following codes. I am stuck with this :') ... Please let me know if you need any other information.

```
int k = 0;
for(; k < lineCounter; k++){
    char *trimmed = strtok(pwd[k], "\n ");
    doesUsrExists = strcmp(arr[0], usr[k]);
    doesPwdExists = strcmp(arr[1], pwd[k]);
    printf("<p> UserExists: %s -- PwdExists: %s", usr[k], pwd[k]);
    printf("<p> UserExists: %d -- PwdExists: %d", doesUsrExists, doesPwdExists);
    if(doesPwdExists == 0 && doesUsrExists == 0){
        bothExists = 0;
        break;
    }
    else
        bothExists = 1;

    doesUsrExists = 0;
    doesPwdExists = 0;
}



printf("<p> UserExists: %d", bothExists);

if(bothExists == 0){
    printf("<h1>Your Password Matches</h1>");
}
else{
    printf("<h1>Wrong username or password</h1>");
}
printf("</body></html>");
```

the `strcmp(arr[1], pwd[k]);` returns different values even though the strings matches.

The output is as follows:
[image]

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). [Edit] your question to copy-paste the output *as text*.

Comment: You are using `strcmp` incorrectly. Change (e.g.) `doesUsrExists = strcmp(arr[0], usr[k]);` into `doesUsrExists = strcmp(arr[0], usr[k]) == 0;`

Comment: As for the problem, have you tried to use a [*debugger*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question) to step through the code and look at the actual contents of the strings? There's no spaces or newlines or other non-printable characters in one or both of the strings? Or print all strings with some kind of delimiter to be able to see it.

Comment: By the way, the logic of `bothExists` seems reversed. It's *false* if there's a match for both username and password, and *true* if there isn't. A better name would be `oneOrTheOtherDoesNotExist`.

Comment: I bet you have a newline at the end of mary's password (maybe everyone's password)

Comment: Anyway the output you posted does NOT match the printf() in you code.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strcmp will work only correct, if both character string are terminated with an null character. If they are missing, the comperation will be failed and furthemore you can corrupt the system.

Comment: the only problem is this code is right, but it doesn't work on a linux server ...  In my localhost it works. And yes I am terminating with "\n ". It's weird for the strcmp() to behave weird on the server ... technically I am lost.

Comment: btw I am, specifically getting this output when both string matches UserExists: -32 -- PwdExists: 32

Comment: I feel your struggle my friend. The safest way is to use strncmp(), the one with the character 'n' in it. This forces you to give the required length to compare, because some read functions don't add 0 terminate char at the end of the string which can give unexpected result that makes your brain BSOD :(